# How to fit a table into Susy grid?

Tags: html-table, width, susy-compass, col, colgroup

I'm trying to figure out how to fit a `<table>` into a Susy grid. Meaning a `<td>` or a `<th>` should be as wide as a Susy grid column or a number of Susy grid columns.

My idea is to set the `<col>` elements to the width returned by Susy's `space()` function. Like:

(HTML)

```
<colgroup>
    <col class="one">
    <col class="two">
    <col class="three">
    <col class="four">
</colgroup>
```

and:

(SCSS)

```
table {
    @include span-columns($total-columns omega);

    colgroup {
        @include reset-columns;
        col {
            span: 1;

            &.one {
                width: space(1);
            }

            &.two {
                width: space(4);
            }

            &.three {
                width: space(4);
            }

            &.four {
                width: space(6);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, it doesn't work ;)

Has anybody built such a table? I would be glad if you let me know!

ps: I'm going to try to set up a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I found out why this isn't working: the `@include span-columns($total-columns omega);` statement makes the table `display: inline`. Setting it back to `display: table` results in the desired behavior.

But I'm wondering, if I just use `width: 100%` instead of using the `@include` for my table...

Comment: Similarly, I'm setting `td { display: block !important; }`